# MSAccess VBA Run code when the user navigates to a different record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that has the navigate buttons on the bottom. 
I would like to run some code every time the user navigates to a different record.

Under which event handler would I place this code? Form_OnLoad only runs the code when I open the form. I'm a bit lost. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [Current Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb214515%28v=office.12%29.aspx).